# Adicionar um dado novo em um dataframe vazio do pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Estou criando um código para ler vários arquivos CSV e extrair dele alguns parâmetros e montar um novo dataframe com pandas, contudo estou enfrentando um problema nesta construção.

Inicialmente pretendia criar um dataframe vazio e conforme fosse lendo os CSVs eu adicionaria as linhas e colunas desejadas.

Por exemplo. Digamos que inicialmente eu tenha o df vazio. Após ler o meu primeiro CSV e adicioná-lo ao df, tenho:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['01/05/2017','01/05/2018','01/05/2019'], index = [0], data=[0,10,11])
```

```
          '01/05/2017' '01/05/2018' '01/05/2019'
'Ana'      0            10           11
```

Depois de varrer o segundo CSV, meu `df` ficaria:

```
          '01/05/2017' '01/05/2018' '01/05/2019' '10/06/2009'
'Ana'      0            10           11           nan
'Joao'     5            11           nan          5
```

De tal forma que ao fim de vários CSVs depois eu tivesse um df tão longo e completo quanto eu necessite.

Eu tentei formar N df diferentes e ir adicionando, mas não funcionou como eu queria. Um dos motivos é que, se por acaso os dados de 'Joao' estiverem distribuídos em mais de 1 csv, o df ficaria:

```
          '01/05/2017' '01/05/2018' '01/05/2019' '10/06/2009'
'Ana'      0            10           11           nan
'Joao'     nan          nan          nan          5
'Joao'     5            nan          nan          nan
'Joao'     nan          11           nan          nan
```

Que não é o formato que quero dos dados.

Existe alguma forma de compor as informações como desejo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece simples de resolver. Supondo que você varreu todos seus arquivos e inseriu todas as linhas no Dataframe. Basta utilizar o código:

```
df.groupby(df.index).sum()
```

#### Exemplo

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[0,10,11,np.nan],
                [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,5],
                [5,np.nan,6,np.nan],
                [np.nan,11,np.nan,np.nan]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['01/05/2017','01/05/2018','01/05/2019','10/06/2009'], index=['Ana','Joao','Joao','Joao'])
```

**Dataframe:**

```
        01/05/2017  01/05/2018  01/05/2019  10/06/2009
Ana     0.0         10.0        11.0        NaN
Joao    NaN         NaN         NaN         5.0
Joao    5.0         NaN         6.0         NaN
Joao    NaN         11.0        NaN         NaN
```

**Utilizando o Groupby**

```
df.groupby(df.index).sum()
```

**Saída:**

```
        01/05/2017  01/05/2018  01/05/2019  10/06/2009
Ana     0.0         10.0        11.0        0.0
Joao    5.0         11.0        6.0         5.0
```

Comment: Obrigado @Leonardo Borges. Funcionou bem aqui!